# How can I switch windows only in one workspace?

Tags: compiz

I enable compiz and switch windows by tab, but I don't want to iterate all windows in all workspaces. How can I switch windows in one workspace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved :-) I use *CompizConfig Settings Manager*, and it can be invoked in bash:    `$ ccsm`. My setting job: **Window Management > Application Program Switcher (or other enabled window switchers) > Next Window = Alt+Tab & Previous Window = Shift+Alt+Tab (not those *`all'* options)**.

Answer (score 2):

The scale plugin might help (Press Super+W)

Comment: Thanks. I solved the issue: CompizConfig Manager > Window Manager > Application Switch Bar > Next Window & Previous Window (not the `all' options).

Comment: @Kejia You should post that as an answer so the next person can benefit!

Comment: @Kejia Yes post it.